# Django: Nested SQL Queries

Tags: python, sql, django

Here are my model classes:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    draw = models.ForeignKey(Draw)
    numbers= models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Draw(models.Model):
    numbers = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I initially have a query which groups all my draw objects and gives the count for each id of draw objects:

```
Ticket.objects.values('draw').annotate(total = models.Count('draw'))
```

This lists out:

```
{'draw': 55L, 'total': 1}
{'draw': 13L, 'total': 16}
{'draw': 12L, 'total': 4}
```

Now what I want to do is display the draw.numbers associated with each line. I tried just directly accessing it via the templates but it didn't work. I was thinking I could do another query with these draw ids to find their associated numbers. I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would follow the foreign key relationship and print all the `numbers` associated with the `draw` objects. I am not sure if the `annotate` result would be the same.

```
Ticket.objects.values('draw', 'draw__numbers')
```

As for querying draw ids to find their associated numbers you can iterate the list and query the `draw` objects as:

```
draw_ids = [i['draw'] for i in input_list]
output_list = Draw.objects.filter(numbers__in=draw_ids)
```

Comment: Wow! It works well. How come you have to use two underscores instead of draw.numbers?

Comment: Double underscore notation is used to query across models with foreign key relationships. More here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets